# PHP web form not showing user's email input in from field

Tags: php, forms, email

I probably didn't word the title too well.

My web form is working in every other way except when I receive a submission from the web form, it says the sender is Apache, when I would prefer it to say either the user's name or the name of the site the form has been submitted from. Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "Form is not submitted!";
exit;
}
if(empty($_POST["name"]) ||
empty($_POST["email"]))
{
    echo "Please complete required fields";
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "ncrbrts@live.com"; 

$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = "Form Submission";
$subject2 = "Copy of Your Form Submission";
$message = $_POST['comment'] . "\n " . "From:" . " " . $_POST['name'] . 
"\n " . "Telephone:" . " " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n " . :Email:" . " " . $_POST

['email'];
$message2 = "Thank you for your enquiry." . "\n " . 

"Here is a copy of your enquiry for your records: " . "\n " . $_POST['comment']
. "\n " . "A member of our team will contact you shortly to discuss your 

requirements.";






$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;


mail($to, $subject, $headers, $message);
mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);
}



header('Location: thank-you.html');


?>
```

I have attempted to change the from variable to say anything else and then just posting the email address in the user's message so I could at least get the information that way. That broke it somewhat! Any help on this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Post your HTML aswell.

Answer (score 0):

hi I am Unable to comment so writing in Answer section:

```
if(empty($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "Form is not submitted!";
exit;
```

what is this for.?